# Keep formatting when posting content from a textarea to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, formatting, ckeditor, textarea

I'm using [USP-Pro](http://plugin-planet.com/) to let users post to a Wordpress blog. I have a textarea input in which they should put the main post content - the one that appears in the Wordpress admin editor. I'd like to keep the text formatting once they submit the form so I'm using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) for that textarea.

```
CKEDITOR.replace('usp-content');
```

Checking the textarea with Firebug while I input the text shows that there actually is some HTML code inside, but when the form is submitted, in the editor I just see the raw text, without any formatting, which is pretty annoying because I lose all the spaces, the new lines and so on.

EDIT:

After various attempts I discovered that the problem is in the Wordpress function `wp_strip_all_tags`, inside the file `wp-includes/formatting.php`. I tried to comment it and it actually posted the content correctly with all the html in place.

Of course I can't just comment the whole function. How can I tell Wordpress to not use it when submitting such posts?

Comment: It might help if you show the code you use to save the content, show the content and load the content into the editor. Also the HTML. Do you meant that the raw text is shown in CKEditor or when you output the edited data from the database? Is the data correct in your database? It's kind of hard to see the big pictuure and what is actually wrong here - there are too many possibilities to start answering.

Comment: I added further info in the original question